# Safety transformer second fault

Tags: transformer, safety

I understand the working principles of these types of transformers as there is no connection to earth on the secondary but still can’t get my head around the safety aspect if there was a second Fault on the circuit for example one of the ends of the secondary ends up being inadvertently earthed and now has a path to earth but then another earth fault occurs will the circuit be safe? Will it disconnected in a safe time?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean by "a safety transformer". What voltages, what power, what output protection, etc.